# Adding variable as url in php curl request

Tags: php

I am trying to integrate a payment gateway in woo-commerce and to confirm the transaction is approved or not, I have to send an API request to the payment gateway endpoint but the problem is that my URL variable ($this->sessionURL)is not working.

I am setting the $this->sessionURL in public function setSessionURL().

````
class Windcave_Sessions{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sessionID = ''; 
        $this->sessionURL= '';
  
        add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', array( $this, 'test_container' ));
        add_action("rest_api_init", array($this, "windcave_query_session"));
    }

    public function test_container(){
        
        $this->sessionURL = $this->setSessionURL($this->sessionID); 
     
        if(empty($this->sessionURL)){
           return;
        }
        else{
            $urlVal = 'https://uat.windcave.com/api/v1/sessions/00001200057642070c56cd51cccd7b03';
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL =>  $this->sessionURL,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization: Basic afa*************='
                ),
            ));
            
            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            
            curl_close($curl);
            $sessionObj = json_decode($response); 
    
            
            foreach ($sessionObj->transactions as $obj) {
                //    check authorization 
                    if($obj->authorised){ 
                        $GLOBALS['authorisedPayment'] = "true"; 
                    }
                    else { 
                        $GLOBALS['authorisedPayment'] = "false"; 
                    }
    
                    $GLOBALS ['responseText'] = $obj->responseText;
            }
                    $returnValue = array(
                        "authorize"=> $GLOBALS['authorisedPayment'], 
                        "responseText"=> $GLOBALS['responseText']
                    ); 
                if($GLOBALS['authorisedPayment'] === "true"){
                    return true;
                }
                else if($GLOBALS['authorisedPayment'] === "false") { 
                    return $returnValue['responseText'];
                }
        }
    }
    
    public function setSessionURL($sessionID){
            return "https://uat.windcave.com/api/v1/sessions/".$sessionID;
    }

  public function windcave_query_session(){ 
    echo  $this->sessionID;
    //update board 
    register_rest_route("inspiry/v1/", "query-session", array(
      "methods" => "POST",
      "callback" => array($this, 'test_container')
      ));
  }
}

$windcaveSession = new Windcave_Sessions();
// add iframe container 
?>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define the $sessionURL for your class to store informations in it.
Is this the full class or a snipped?

If it is the full class you have to define the variable in this way:

```
class foo{
var $sessionURL = "";
}
```

After that you are able to use it with `$this->sessionURL`